# Extrude not working in Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, extrude

I can't extrude in blender 2.8.
So I merged a cube at its center.
I went to vertice mode and edit mode too. I tried to extrude the vertex but when I do it just duplicates it. I thought the problem was because it was a merged shape. So, I make another cube without merging it and extruded it. Guess what happened. It duplicated again! What do I do to extrude in blender 2.8? I press E and it doesn't work. Did they change the shortcut or what?

Comment: Extrusion doesn't work on closed geometry, select a face instead. As to vertex extruding make sure vertex is selected first

Comment: see the [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26858/69959) [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26856/69959)

Comment: If you convert an object to a mesh and then extrude it, it will not work. extrude first and then convert the mesh.

Comment: Maybe you are on edge or face selection.
Try switching to vertex select

Answer (score 2):

i do exactly what you say, and it works. Just download the latest 2.8 build
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The new extrude hotkey for Blender 2.8+ is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.